# DATEADD to calculate PYTD (Jan 1 till today's date) in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a daily sales data for 3-4 years. I want to create the YTD and Prior Year To Date sales measure that will be updated daily. That is it should always be from beginning of the year (selected) to TODAY or the last day of the data (1 day lag from today and max date).

I used Sameperiodlastyear but it is problematic at the beginning of the month as it compares say Jan 1, 2022-June 8 2022 with Jan 1, 2021 with June 30, 2021.

Any suggestion how I can create a modified prior year to date measure to address this nuance?

Comment: See https://www.daxpatterns.com/standard-time-related-calculations/ - Use `DATEADD` to shift dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard solution for the case. First, you get all dates, with a DATESYTD() function, for the current year or last visible year  up today or last visible day, then you offset it.

```
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DATESYTD(‘Date’[Date]))
```

It is equal to

```
DATEADD(DATESYTD(‘Date’[Date]),-1,YEAR))
```

Try this if you want to get exact days set:

```
VAR FirstDayThisYear = 
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(STARTOFYEAR(‘Date’[Date])
VAR LastDayThisYear = 
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(
                          LASTDATE(‘Date’[Date])
        )
VAR SetOfDates= 
        DATESBETWEEN(
                    ‘Date’[Date]
                    ,FirstDayThisYear 
                    ,LastDayThisYear 
        )
RETURN 
    SetOfDates
```

Comment: Thank you Mik. I tried both of your suggestions but i still receive the same value as what I would have received if i just used SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Date[Date]), which is the entire month of June although the data is up to June 8th. Should i specify max date somewhere?

Comment: What value you get with  a LASTDATE() function? Its sytax is - LASTDATE ( <Dates> )

Comment: DATESYTD returns dates till last visible date. it means that if you have, for instane, dates till the end of year and they are not filtered then you will get all dates up to the 31 of december.

Comment: I've added new solutions for your case. Hopfully this ill work.

Comment: Hi Mik, thank you for adding new solutions. Unfortunately i still get the same answer as just standard same period last year formula. My lastdate(Date) is always the day before today (our data has a lag of 1 day). When i filter my date to just that available last date in filters, my totals for PYTD is correct, but when i unfilter, total jumps into calculating the entire month of June for PYTD.

Comment: Hi user... ). What visual shows you result? do you have a hierarchy for dates? Do you have a Caledar tadle? If yes, did you mark it as the date table? It would be nice to see a screenshot and the code. "What value you get with a LASTDATE() function? Its sytax is - LASTDATE ( <Dates> ) "

Comment: I think I’ve got the point. Now I’m on trip. I’ll try to give an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I've changed the last suggestion. Please, check

Comment: Thanks so much Mik. I tried incorporating the suggested code (for SetofDates) but given that I am still new, i wasn't able to get it work. Should i incorporate it as: Dates = VAR .... (the code); then SamePeriodLastYear(DateYTD(Dates))? How do i embed the "SetofDates" into the Dateadd or sameperiodlastyear formula? Thank again

Comment: @user9832031, hello again. The SetOfDates is filter of dates. It is what that you have to use in your CALCULATE(). All manipulations with dates should be done before you get SetOfDates. If you attach the sample of your pbix with slicers it help to get the point. Or you can make dummy data tables that repeats the model. And output sample as well.